# ANOVA with multiple factors not working

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to have my data be analyzed using the multiple factors of depth and date of sampling. The code used and levels produced listed below.

```
date <- factor(Amount_allSampling_Depth$date)
depth <- factor(Amount_allSampling_Depth$depth)
depth_date <- date:depth
levels(depth_date)
[1] "2016-08-08:5"  "2016-08-08:10" "2016-08-08:15" "2016-08-08:20" "2016-08-15:5" 
[6] "2016-08-15:10" "2016-08-15:15" "2016-08-15:20" "2016-08-22:5"  "2016-08-22:10"
[11] "2016-08-22:15" "2016-08-22:20" "2016-08-29:5"  "2016-08-29:10" "2016-08-29:15"
[16] "2016-08-29:20" "2016-09-05:5"  "2016-09-05:10" "2016-09-05:15" "2016-09-05:20"
[21] "2016-09-12:5"  "2016-09-12:10" "2016-09-12:15" "2016-09-12:20" "2016-09-19:5" 
[26] "2016-09-19:10" "2016-09-19:15" "2016-09-19:20" "2016-10-03:5"  "2016-10-03:10"
[31] "2016-10-03:15" "2016-10-03:20" "2016-10-10:5"  "2016-10-10:10" "2016-10-10:15"
[36] "2016-10-10:20" "2016-10-17:5"  "2016-10-17:10" "2016-10-17:15" "2016-10-17:20"
[41] "2016-10-24:5"  "2016-10-24:10" "2016-10-24:15" "2016-10-24:20"
```

When I try to do an ANOVA on of my classes of data ex. Dinoflagellates.

```
Dinoflagellates <- Amount_allSampling_Depth$Dinoflagellates 
anova(lm(Dinoflagellates~depth_date))
```

I got the warning message:

> ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable.

Could someone help to find out how I could make it work so I can do multiple factor analyses?

Comment: This post could be related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82438/warning-in-r-anova-f-tests-on-an-essentially-perfect-fit-are-unreliable

Comment: How many observations are there per factor level?

Comment: There are three sampled depths per sample date. Meaning that every date has 3 observations and every depth has 11 observations.